# Consuming F# Async from C#

Tags: f#, async-await

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
namespace Library1

open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Threading
open System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging
open System

type public Class1() =

    let printThread (message) = 
        printfn "%s %A" message Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

    let bar = 
        printThread ("first bar")
        async { 
            printThread ("first async")
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            printThread "last async"
        }

    member this.X() =  bar
```

I would like to use this class and invoke X from C#. The problem is X returns an Async<'T>. However, it is bad practice to expose F# specific types. So best practice is to return a Task. However Async.StartAsTask is kind of problematic since it will cause the code run in a seperate thread. What I want is I want to return a Task but also it should behave as Async.StartImmediate. Thus the non async part of the code should run in the original main thread. **Here I assume I run it from UI thread** so that all calls will return the same thread ID. In other words I want a Async.StartImmediate but returning a task.
Is this achieavable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Works exactly as I want (unlike the question this version returns an int as well which is plus):

```
type public Class1() = 
    let printThread (message) = printfn "%s %A" message Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

    let bar = 
        printThread ("first bar")
        async { 
            printThread ("first async")
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            printThread "last async"
            return 1232
         }

    member this.convertToTask<'T> (asyn : Async<'T>) = 
       let tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<'T>()
       let t1 = tcs1.Task
       Async.StartWithContinuations
        (
          asyn 
          , (fun (k) -> tcs1.SetResult(k)), (fun exn -> tcs1.SetException(exn)), fun exn -> ())
        t1

    member this.X() : Task<int> =  (bar |> this.convertToTask)
```

Comment: If I run this, I get output like this: `X 8, first bar 8, first async 8, last async 11`, just like in my (simpler) answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry you are probably trying it from a console app, while pending the main thread. I run my code from UI thread, and all print statements return the same ID. Your code has the problem calling RunSynchronously. It will either create a dead lock or run last statement in a different thread

Comment: +1 This is what I'd have written if I read the question properly!

Answer (score 3):

You can turn `Async<'T>` into `Task<'T>` using the `Async.StartAsTask<'T>` method.

I'd generally recommend making things easy for the C# users and extend the F# implementation with an additional method that returns `Task<'T>`. Following the usual naming convention, you can call the F# version `AsyncFoo` and the C#-friendly version `FooAsync`.

Looking at your example, I'd go with something like this:

```
type public Class1() =

    let printThread (message) = 
        printfn "%s %A" message Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

    let bar = 
        printThread ("first bar")
        async { 
            printThread ("first async")
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            printThread "last async"
        }

    member this.AsyncFoo() =  bar

    /// Expose C#-friendly asynchronous method that returns Task
    member this.FooAsync() = Async.StartAsTask(bar)
    /// Expose C#-friendly asynchronous method that returns Task
    /// and takes cancellation token to support cancellation...
    member this.FooAsync(cancellationToken) = 
      Async.StartAsTask(bar, ?cancellationToken=cancellationToken)
```

Comment: As I stated, this will not satisify my question, causing non async code running in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining `X` like this?

```
member this.X() = 
    let t = new Task(fun () -> bar |> Async.StartImmediate)
    t.RunSynchronously()
    t
```

As far as I can tell, it does what you want. At least, this C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine("X " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
var c = new Class1();            
c.X().Wait();

Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

prints this output:

```
X 7
first bar 7
first async 7
last async 11
```

Here, as seen from C#, `X` has the signature `Task X()`.

Comment: All thread Id's must be 7. I actually found the answer I will post below